# Paths in c# : WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I am making a customize window for which I need to draw certain path in canvas, but all I have to do is make the path in c# instead of XAML, I have written paths in xaml but unable to convert them in c#..
Here is my paths

```
 <Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="appbar_close" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0" Margin="1350,20,-252,302" >
                        <Path Width="10" Height="10" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 26.9166,22.1667L 37.9999,33.25L 49.0832,22.1668L 53.8332,26.9168L 42.7499,38L 53.8332,49.0834L 49.0833,53.8334L 37.9999,42.75L 26.9166,53.8334L 22.1666,49.0833L 33.25,38L 22.1667,26.9167L 26.9166,22.1667 Z " MouseLeftButtonUp="mouseleftbuttonup" />
                    </Canvas>
                    <Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="appbar_minus" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0" Margin="1310,24,-211,302">
                        <Path Width="10" Height="3" Canvas.Left="0" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 19,38L 57,38L 57,44L 19,44L 19,38 Z "/>
                    </Canvas>
                    <Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="appbar_app" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0" Margin="1330,19,-231,302">
                        <Path Width="8" Height="8" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="3" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 18,23L 58,23L 58,53L 18,53L 18,23 Z M 54,31L 22,31L 22,49L 54,49L 54,31 Z "/>
                    </Canvas>
```

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for creating a Canvas and adding a Path to it in code-behind goes a little something like this:

```
var canvas = new Canvas
             {
                 Clip = Geometry.Parse("F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0"),
                 Margin = new Thickness(1330, 19, -231, 302)
             };

var path = new Path
           {
               Width = 8,
               Height = 8,
               Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
               Stretch = Stretch.Fill,
               Data = Geometry.Parse("F1 M 18,23L 58,23L 58,53L 18,53L 18,23 Z M 54,31L 22,31L 22,49L 54,49L 54,31 Z")
           };

canvas.Children.Add(path);
Canvas.SetTop(path, 3);
Canvas.SetLeft(path, 3);
```

Disclaimer: This was not tested.